# How to make blender listen to a commandport so other apps can send code to it?

Tags: scripting

How to make blender listen to a commandport so other apps can send code to it?

I wanted to ask if there's a simple script or code to tell blender to listen to any code sent by a other app by listening to a commandport simmlar to maya's method.

In maya the only code I need is

> import maya.cmds as cmds
>
> cmds.commandPort(name=":7002", sourceType="python")
>
> cmds.commandPort(name=":7001", sourceType="mel")

At this point In maya I can send any code with what ever app I want in python by sending it through port 7002, simple and easy.

I want to know if I can do something similar with blender
I tried SublimeBlender but it only worked with sublime when I tried using other apps to send code to port 8006 nothing happens, I need a less complex way to make blender listen to a port to take incoming code from any app not just Sublime.

Answer (score 1):

In short: AFAIK Blender doesn't come with such a feature built-in.

You could start an [HTTP server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) and listen to incoming requests. You'll have to use multithreading (can get hairy) if you don't want to block Blender's UI, though. Another approach could be an [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) socket server. Also see this SE question: [send instructions to blender from external application](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15670/send-instructions-to-blender-from-external-application).

Be sure that you only run this on trusted networks, though, and/or use proper encryption & authentication to protect your Blender.