# TCP Server inside Blender

Tags: python, operator, external-applications

I'm trying to implement a tcp server inside blender with a time operator using asyncio. but the code always crash the UI. I know there is a way to do this inside blender since some people have achieved it already...i found that blender cloud addon..can be the way to go but i don't know where to start any help???

This is the code im trying to mix with the blender cloud addon.. i think i need to integrate the async_loop.py file but i don't know how to start

```
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
   data = await reader.read(100)
   message = data.decode()
   addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
   print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))

   print("Send: %r" % message)
   writer.write(data)
   await writer.drain()

   print("Close the client socket")
   writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
   loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

right now the code im using is by creating a file and reading it with a time operator like it is described here

[send instructions to blender from external application](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15670/send-instructions-to-blender-from-external-application)

Comment: Since you don't post any code nor details about the crash, there is little we can tell about your situation. You could take a look at how I integrated asyncio with the [Blender Cloud add-on](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BCA/).

Comment: Hi, @dr.Sybren, sorry about that... i found the blender cloud add-on but im still relatively new to python so im trying to understand the code....i updated my question so you can understand better my issue

Answer (score 3):

`loop.run_forever()` will make your script block Blender itself. You have to call `loop.stop()` before that, so that `run_forever()` will only do a single iteration over the asyncio tasks that can be run at that time. Calling this single iteration then has to be performed frequently. This is what the [asyncio.loop](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BCA/browse/master/blender_cloud/async_loop.py$127) modal operator is for.

This is quite a complex thing to attempt when you're relatively new to Python. Probably it would be easier to just use multi-processing and start your server in a separate process, instead of using asyncio.

Comment: mm, i understand is complex...still  a separate server is not that different from what i have now....and is not what i'm looking for...i understand the theory of the loop run forever and loop stop...just need more guidance on how asyncio.loop works.... thanks anyway